# Unable to execute QGIS algorithm while taking Input raster directly from AWS S3 account

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, gdalwarp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a raster file (.TIF) in my AWS S3 account. I am using GDAL to open that .TIF file and to save the reprojected .TIF file to my local computer using QGIS GDAL 'Warp (reproject)' algorithm as given below.

```
ds = gdal.Open('/vsis3/s3bucket/input.tif')
processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", {'INPUT':ds,'SOURCE_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32643'),'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'/home/user/Desktop/reprojected.tif'})
```

I am able to open the input.tif in my AWS S3 account using gdal.Open.

```
ds
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f4ea96f1750> >
```

But, while executing the reprojecting algorithm, I am getting error.

```
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value
```

Meanwhile, when I give a raster file which is in my local computer as input.tif (instead of directly giving the raster file from my AWS S3 account), this same QGIS processing.run algorithm is getting executed.

I wonder, whether the QGIS processing.run algorithms (including 'Warp (reproject)' can only take an input file only from local computer or whether it can take input file from AWS S3 directly as arguments.

I am able to get all raster statistics and other QGIS functionalities by giving the AWS S3 path of the raster as argument. It is only during the execution of processing.run algorithms, I am getting the error.

I understand that QGIS processing.run algorithms will take only INPUT as the path of raster in terms of 'strings', but ds = ('/vsis3/s3bucket/input.tif') =  >. It is not a string, it is a gdal object.

How can I solve this issue ?